# How convert ML VectorUDT features from .mllib to .ml type

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

Using pySpark ML API in version 2.0.0 for a linear regression simple example, I get an error with new ML library.

The code is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext =SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

data=sc.parallelize(([1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[4,8]))
def f2Lp(inStr):
    return (float(inStr[0]), Vectors.dense(inStr[1]))
Lp = data.map(f2Lp)
testDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(Lp,["label","features"])
(trainingData, testData) = testDF.randomSplit([0.8,0.2]) 
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
lr=LinearRegression()
model=lr.fit(trainingData)
```

and  error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.'
```

how I should transform vector features from .mllib to .ml type ?

Answer (score 9):

From Spark2.0 use

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

instead of

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 
This problem can be solved by using the right imports 
That is

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

Other way is using a mapper function you convert mllib vector to string and the parse it back to a ml vector.